# Computer won't start, IO error, dropped to initramfs

Tags: boot

I was just starting my computer, I have version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.4 and I keep getting this what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Hello! We can't see what you see. Do you mind showing us?

Comment: http://lina-aymen.tumblr.com/post/139661067906 here is a picture

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo I think he means the GRUB screen (version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.4).

Comment: Sure, now we can see. But when I dropped my message there was no picture at all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: no problem! So I put it on a flash how can I install it with the commands, and GRUB menu? and should the flash drive contain nothing but the software?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @DavidFoerster but it reads "error loading journal" in the picture, looks like a filesystem issue.

Comment: Before you are going to reinstall and possibly overwrite all data you may want to try to recover and backup files you want to keep: http://askubuntu.com/q/59064/40581
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery
http://askubuntu.com/q/381518/40581
http://askubuntu.com/q/7809/40581 sorry for the link bombing, I couldn't find one single answer that does it all.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a problem. This is the GRUB (GRand Unified Bootloader) menu screen. It's Ubuntu's default bootloader. Its function is to load and start the Linux kernel and some needed parts of the system.

This very useful when you have more than one operating system in your computer.

If it's **not** your case, you can hide this screen by running the following commands in an Ubuntu terminal:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

Find the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` line and change its value from whatever it is to `0`. Save the file and exit. Again, in a terminal run:

`sudo update-grub`

When it finishes, reboot to see if you still get the menu.

Comment: I am still getting the menu :( , how can I open the terminal when the only options I can choose from are these, edit commands and command-line

Comment: Look, you just have to press Enter when "Ubuntu" is selected! Then you'll go to Ubuntu! This menu is not a problem. Understand now?

Comment: Of course and this is what I am getting http://lina-aymen.tumblr.com/post/139663974776

Comment: Well, then why didn't you show us this error before? I couldn't know with your broad question. I suggest reinstalling.

Comment: where can I download this version online please?

Comment: http://www.ubuntu.com/download . You can also take a look at the different Ubuntu flavors if you want: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-flavours .

Answer (score 0):

You have either a file system problem or a failing hard drive.

First boot from a live media to confirm exactly what the issue is.

[Check SMART status of the drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-drive-on-ubuntu-14-04-through-15-10/528077#528077) to see if it's failing

**If you have critical data on the drive you and you don't have a [backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) you should create a backup image on an external drive before continuing.**

Boot from Live media and open a terminal and run `fsck /dev/sdXY` (where X is the drive designator {it appears to be a in your case} and Y is the suspect partition number) to attempt to repair the filesystem. The answer to Fix? is Y

If any of this is unclear please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/737042/edit) your question to include what you tried and the results and leave me a comment.