# how to recover data from partition without permissions?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-call-fastboot

I have an internal drive with a partition I am no longer able to access:

`You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents`

Reason for it is a windows OS with fast boot. There are many solutions provided for this but none of them worked.

`sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o ro /dev/sda4 /media/windows/
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda4' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?`

ntfsfix ends in unrecoverable error:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4
Mounting volume... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

.

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>
```

I tried e2fsck but that did not work.

The only working solution is to boot into windows and disable fast boot, but I can no longer boot into windows.

I only want to recover my user data somehow is there a way?

Edit: Meanwhile I deleted all partitions with only Data left. This is how it looks like: 
[image]

thank you

Comment: You can mount the partition read only, as explained in this [existing answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: "Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk."  generally you would use you windows install media for that. if ntsfix does not fix it the problem is also not likely to be hibenation ;)

Comment: ok, but I read that fsck is the linux equivalent command for chkdsk?

Comment: true but you are missing 1 very important part -for linux filesystems-. The excludes windows filesystems.

Comment: but the data I want to recover is not on the windows filesystem. It has ext4. Meanwhile I deleted all NTFS partitions and placed a screenshot of my partition table

Comment: sorry but you started with ntfs-g3 on sda4. that would suggest it is ntfs, you used ntfsfix on sda4 that would suggest ntfs. but it is actually ext4?!  you problably need this: https://askubuntu.com/a/381759/15811 but DO make a backup of that partition if you did not yet do that,

Comment: I was able to recover my data with the following command: `sudo cp -R /media/m/Acer_S/ ~/Recovery`

Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your help.

Comment: Even better solution would be `sudo chown -R $USER: /media/m/Acer_S/`